# Two bones acting as one

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

So I was trying to rig a Dino model from a ps1 dev disc. I used rigify, and for the tail I used one of the arm presets. I didn't make sure alot of bones for smooth bending, but some sets of bones are acting as one, making the problem even worse. Here's the example:

[image]

[image]

Any way to fix this?

**Edit**
If I do have to redo this, is there anyway to get the 'arm' to have more bones so I can have the nice inverse kinematics?